# How can I write this function in typescript by using an interface?

Tags: typescript

How can I write this code by using interface? Or maybe by using `declare function`?

```
function getProperty<Type, Key extends keyof Type>(obj: Type, key: Key) {
  return obj[key];
}
```

[Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints)

Comment: This question is unclear to me; what are you actually trying to accomplish?  The code is already written, and there's no obvious place to "use an interface".  And why would you use `declare function`?  Are you trying to get rid of the function implementation and just make a declaration file for it?  I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as it's written as a type. Just transfer type definition inside the interface:

```typescript
interface GetProperty {
    <Type, Key extends keyof Type>(obj: Type, key: Key): Type[Key];
}

const getProperty: GetProperty = (obj, key) => obj[key]
```